# Can't access class before other class c++

Tags: c++, class, function, header

Hey guys I'm having trouble setting up a header file the way I need it to be. To simplify my question here's an example:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H    

class Parent
{
    Child mykid; //a kid of mine
    void dosomething(void);
};

class Child
{
        Parent * mydad; //pointer back to my dad
        void dosomething(void);
};    

#endif // MYHEADER_H
```

I'm basicly needing to use one class inside of another class before the compiler even knows about it. Is there a way to tell the compiler about my classes before I define there insides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
class Parent;
class Child
{
        Parent * mydad; //pointer back to my dad
        void dosomething(void);
};    
class Parent
{
    Child mykid; //a kid of mine
    void dosomething(void);
};
```

Suggestion: move them in separate headers, forward-declare `Parent` in `Child.h` and `#include "Child.h"` in `Parent.h`.

`Parent` needs a full definition of `Child` to work, `Child` only needs a declaration.

I also suggest you stop using raw pointers.

Comment: Thanks this will hopefully work for what I need, and thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
class Parent;

class Child { Parent * dad; };
class Parent { Child kid; };
```

To define a class, all class members must have a **complete type**. `class Parent;` makes `Parent` an *incomplete type*. However, for *any* type `T`, whether complete or incomplete, `T *` is *always* a complete type.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent;

class Child
{
        Parent * mydad; // it's enough to know class exists
        void dosomething(void);
};  

class Parent
{
    Child mykid; // We must know size of a class
    void dosomething(void);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Parent` contains a `Child` object, so its definition must come after the definition of `Child`; that is one of the uses of a type that requires a full definition.

`Child` only contains a pointer to a `Parent`, so it only needs a declaration of the `Parent` type.

So you need:

```
// Declaration
class Parent;

// Definitions
class Child
{
    Parent * mydad; // type can be incomplete
    void dosomething(void);
};
class Parent
{
    Child mykid; // type must be complete
    void dosomething(void);
};
```

When a type has been declared but not defined, it's called *incomplete*. You can do various things with incomplete types, including declaring pointers and references to it, and using it as the parameter or return types in function declaration. You can't create an object of the type (and that includes declaring a non-static class member of that type), because that requires the definition in order to know various facts such as its size.